# CSS submenu is disturbing the parent li

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem with CSS menu. I want the parent `li` not to be disturbed by the sub menu. I want the parent list to have widths equal to the text contents they have itself but not the inner `ul`. I don't want to give the parent list specific width. Here is the image.[image]

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav{
    padding-left: 70px;
    line-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav > li{
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: yellow;
}
.subm{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    background: #252525;
    padding:  0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.subm > li{
    color: #ffde00;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-family: decker;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Languages
            <ul class="subm">
                <li>C</li>
                <li>C++</li>
                <li>java</li>
                <li>c#</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked in your jsfiddle  @Hanzallah Afgan. Try this

Remove overflow:hidden css property for .nav, then the sub menu will display

Comment: Good. That was too simple. I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: you are welcome :)  But the credit also goes to @gopalraju

Answer (score 3):

Add `position:absolute` to `.subm`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eryo2kjg/

Comment: Is it not possible without absolute position?

Comment: Please check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaeze2so/). Why the sub menu is not displayed above all?

Comment: @HanzallahAfgan: why should it be without `position:absolute`?